# Seeking GIS information on worldwide cases of wildfires

Tags: data, emergency-services

I am developing some case studies on wildfire cases around the globe, some examples include California (2007), Australia (2009), Moscow (2010), Valparaiso in Chile (2014), and so on.

Where could be a good start for gathering layers regarding the urban areas affected, infrastructure, nature features, and specifics of the fires such as perimeters?

Any tips on GIS libraries or sites from these cases?

Comment: Might be suitable for the [opendata.se] beta Stack Exchange

Comment: US http://www.arcgis.com/apps/PublicInformation/index.html?appid=0c12ac1e89c24075a2be145f4db6caf5 has many sources for the US (click layers)

Comment: In the US, there are two main levels/places to look. One is USDA National Forest Service, as they tend to be the primary fighting agency and often have detailed reports on individual fires. The other level is the local jurisdiction, for example the county. Depending on frequency of fires and available budget, some counties have fairly extensive resources (for example: http://www.bouldercounty.org/property/forest/pages/bcwildfires.aspx).

Comment: Ok, narrowing down my research in the US to the San Diego and LA areas, I came across http://rdw.sandag.org/Default.aspx, http://portal.gis.ca.gov/geoportal/catalog/main/home.page, https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/GDGHome_StatusMaps.aspx, and http://map.sdsu.edu/ and also collected documentation from CAL Fire.

Comment: For information in Victoria (Australia, specifically 2009 fires) I found https://www.data.vic.gov.au/... Worldwide information on fires can also be found here https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms/active-fire-data#tab-content-6

Comment: I am now searching for European cases of wildfires, especially in the Mediterranean (Spain, Portugal, Italy, Greece). Any databases/catalogs for these countries?

Comment: From a global perspective one good resource is the ESA ATSR World Fire Atlas (http://gcmd.nasa.gov/records/GCMD_ATSR_FIRE_ATLAS.html). It sounds like it is too general for what you are looking for though.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a list of resources (by no means comprehensive) that may be useful to you:

NASA's MODIS provides imagery to identify wildfires: https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/data/hazards-and-disasters/fires
This website provides weekly global snapshots of fires: http://lance-modis.eosdis.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/imagery/firemaps.cgi
This website provides regional snapshots of fires for 24 hrs, 48 hrs, 72 hrs, and 7 days: https://earthdata.nasa.gov/data/near-real-time-data/firms/active-fire-data

The EU's Joint Research Center provides a global burnt area dataset for the year 2000 using SPOT imagery (1km resolution): http://bioval.jrc.ec.europa.eu/products/burnt_areas_gba2000/global2000.php

Cases of fires in the United States are updated daily on the USGS' Geospatial Multi-Agency Coordination site. Wildfire cases are downloadable as shapefiles or as a kml file: http://www.geomac.gov/

Geoscience Australia's Sentinal website tracks wildfires in Australia: http://sentinel.ga.gov.au/